# Django creating object from POST

Tags: python, django, http

I have a question regarding Djanog views

here is a sample code

```
def example register ( request ) :
if request.method == ’POST ’ :
username = request.POST.get ( ’ username ’ )
password = request.POST.get ( ’ password ’ )
email = request.POST.get (’email’)
user = User.objects .create_user ( username
, email
, password )
user . save ()
return HttpResponseRedirect (
’/ example /login / ’)
```

In the above example we are taking the values one  by one i.e username, password etc. If I have many such fields, then how can I do it in one single line, i was thinking to use dict's but can not find a way. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Changed the title - this has nothing whatsoever to do with HttpResponse.

Answer (score 5):

you should be using forms[1] and model-forms [2] to collect such data from the request.

[1] http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

[2] http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever do it like that anyway?

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
and then handle it like that:
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    newuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login (request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/page/which/is/not/logginpage')#cause user is already logged in
```

Probably not the most elegenat way, but it should describe well enough, how to use form and then authenticate someone & log him in.